# Show pickerInput depending on checkBoxInput result R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a dynamic UI for my shiny dashboard. Here, I want to show a `pickerInput` field only when the input in a `checkboxGroup` is a specific value. For example, when the input from the `checkboxGroup` field is `A`, I want to show the `pickerInput` field, otherwise I want to show a different input field.

Currently, the part of my code looks, using `conditionalPanel`, like the following:

```
output$UI_selection <- renderUI({


tagList(
  p(tags$i("Define the network")),

  checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "choice1", 
                   label = "Make a choice", 
                   choices = list("A", "B")
  ),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input$choice1 == 'A'",
  pickerInput(inputId = "select1",
              label = "Select first:",
              choices = list(
                "Hierarchies" = grouplist_1),
              selected = NULL,
              options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `none-selected-text` = "Select hierarchy", `live-search` = TRUE, title = "Select hierarchy"),
              multiple = FALSE
   )
 ) 

 )
})
```

However, this doesn't work and shows both the `checkboxGroupInput` as well as the `PickerInput`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `shiny` package functions (such as `conditionalPanel`) translate all of the R language code you supply into JS. Conditions you supply in `conditionalPanel` need to be interpretable in JS, which uses `.` in place of `$`.

You need to replace your `condition = "input$choice1 == 'A'"` with `condition = "input.choice1 == 'A'"`.

Full working app is here:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("UI_selection")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$UI_selection <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      p(tags$i("Define the network")),

      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "choice1", 
                         label = "Make a choice", 
                         choices = list("A", "B")
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.choice1 == 'A'",
                       pickerInput(inputId = "select1",
                                   label = "Select first:",
                                   choices = list(
                                     "Hierarchies" = c("X","Y","Z")),
                                   selected = NULL,
                                   options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `none-selected-text` = "Select hierarchy", `live-search` = TRUE, title = "Select hierarchy"),
                                   multiple = FALSE
                       )
      ) 
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```